# Android requests are a lot slower when on WiFi

Tags: android, graphql, retrofit, android-wifi, apollo-client

I am building an app with `retrofit` and `graphQL` and [Apollo Client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) for Android. The app works fine when on the mobile network, but, if I switch to WiFi, it is really slow (even though the internet speed is good. 17.5 Mbps for download and 10.4 Mbps for upload with 6ms)
I know this question is subjective and ambiguous, but I hope someone came across the same or similar issue and managed to solve it.
Also, the why I posted this question is, I believe that the app was faster (even on WiFi before), so maybe is something I changed, a library I updated...
Whatever code you need, I will post here, but I am not sure if will be needed.

**EDIT**
When on Network provider, the requests take from 80ms to 300ms. On Wifi, from 30s to 49s!

**EDIT 2**
Happens when connected on certain WiFis. But only my app. Should be a WiFi issue if all apps are slow, right?

**EDIT 3** Adding interceptor and logs:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("HEADER 1", "PARAM 1")
            .addHeader("HEADER 2", "PARAM 2")
            .build()

        val t1 = System.nanoTime()
        logD(
            "AppResponse",
            String.format(
                "Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
                request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()
            )
        )

        val response: Response = chain.proceed(request)

        val t2 = System.nanoTime()
        logD(
            "AppResponse",
            String.format(
                "Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
                response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6, response.headers()
            )
        )

        //this was because, if error, I was not able to get error message on GraphQL callbacks.
        val updatedResponse = when (response.code()) {
            in 400..499 ->
                response.newBuilder()
                    .code(200)
                    .build()
            else -> response
        }

        updatedResponse
    }.build()
```

And the responses are:

**On mobile network:**

AppResponse: Received response for myLink.com in 347.9ms

**On WiFi:**

AppResponse: Received response for myLink.com in 41203.5ms

Thanks.

Comment: if a 'few huge jsons needed' counts in MB then this is a huge mistake

Comment: Might be 1.4Mb tops. So that should not be an issue. And again, the app works smoothly on mobile network. Also, those files are being cached. So eill be downloaded (for explanation purposes) once. Also, a "normal" request takes about 30s... I will remove that 'huge' comment because could be confusing.

Comment: use apollo-link to log time of response[-s], compare with component rendering time

Comment: I searched for it and does not appear for Android. I added an Interceptor and there is where I get response time. Also, is not only graphql, is happening on retrofit too. Should I add the interceptor log?

Comment: if not only graphql affected then change question tags to more problem related (java, retrofit)

Comment: check if it is DNS resolving related - use IP instead of domain name in url ... ping, traceroute (from laptop) through WIFI link (hot spot) to target/API host?

Comment: Like on [this link](https://github.com/qiniu/android-netdiag) to check status? Or how so?

Comment: could be ... but at start simply use IP instead of domain name `http://x.x.x.x/graphql` ... then recreate request using postman ... then deeper network tests